# Set title of a titleWindow using AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using a titleWindow as a container for a popup (flex 3.5). I want to set the title of the window using a variable. Any idea, how do we do that?

Answer (score 3):

What is the type of your variable?  Also, do you want to set this in ActionScript or MXML?

If you want to set it in MXML, just do:

```
<mx:TitleWindow title="{myVariable}" />
```

In ActionScript its just:

```
titleWindow.title = myVariable;
```

If your variable is not a String, you'll need to call `toString()` prior to setting it.

Answer (score 0):

titleWindow.title = "myTitle"